# Store strings from file into dynamically alocated array

Tags: c

I am reading words from a file, exact number 2243. And I am trying to store them inside array so I can read them later on the program. Code is inside function. The file doesn't have sentences, just words one below the other.

```
char** fill_word_array(char* filename){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int lines = 0;

    char str[20];
    char *array[i][j];

    array[i][j] = malloc(lines * sizeof(char*));


    FILE * fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF)
    {
        lines++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", lines);

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    array[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * lines);
    for(i = 0; i <= lines; i++)
    {
        strcpy(array[lines][j], str);
        printf("%s", array[i][j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code prints only the last word of the file as shown here http://tinypic.com/r/2zhjmgx/9.

Comment: Since you are attempting to create zero-sized arrays, and arrays are not dynamic in any way (once defined, they will have the size specified in the definition, in your case zero). Attempting to use *any* index in your arrays will be out of bounds and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There are also some other "weird" things in your code regarding the array, and how you attempt to allocate it. I recommend you take a few steps back, read a little more about pointers and dynamic allocation (and **re**allocation) before continuing.

Comment: `int i = 0, j = 0;char *array[i][j];` is suspicious; and you do not store any word in your array, do you? The only word you use is that in `str`, which contains the last word read in the first loop.

Comment: By the way, note that the [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format `"%s"` reads *space delimited **words***, not "lines".

Comment: There are lots of problems here. Starting with your first malloc(), which equates to: `array[i][j] = malloc(0 * 1);`.  STRONG SUGGESTION: re-think your design; re-write your program :(

Comment: Oh, and you don't actually *read* anything (properly). The only thing you read is the *words* when counting "lines". Then you rewind the file to the start, and loop over the number of "lines" and use the last item you read while counting "lines", you don't read the actual words again.

Comment: As Some programmer dude pointed out, `fscanf` reads _words_ and _not_ lines, so, if you want _lines_ you'd want `fgets` instead [which is faster].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even theVLA  array of size zero has undefined behaviour - *"each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero."*

Answer (score 1):

A declaration like `char *array[i][j]` with `i==0` and `j==0` will reserve an array of size 0, such that even position `array[0][0]` is not legally accessible (undefined behaviour). So when you write `array[i][j] = malloc(lines * sizeof(char*))`, you already write to `array[0][0]` yielding UB.

Usually one gets punished by the community for providing the solution to somebody asking for help and thereby steeling him the chance to make the experiences on his own. For your maturity level, however, it seems to me that the exercise is to hard, and therefore I'll provide a solution following your approach and describe the things that are to consider.

Hope it helps.

With your approach you need to...

1. count the words
2. allocate space for "words * sizeof(char*)" +
   one word to store a `NULL`-pointer at the end (otherwise the users
   of your result will not know where to stop).
3. rewind and read in every word in a loop;
4. in the loop, make a copy of the temporary word content and store it in the array
5. after the loop, write the
   final NULL-pointer.
6. return the array (and tell the user that he
   will have to free memory later)

Here's the code:

```
char** fill_word_array(char* filename){

    int words = 0;
    char str[100];
    char **array;

    FILE * fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF)
    {
        words++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", words);

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (words+1));
    for(int i = 0; i < words && fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF; i++)
    {
        array[i] = strdup(str);
    }
    array[words] = NULL;

    return array;
}

int main() {

    char **array = fill_word_array("someFile.txt");
    for (int i=0; array[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, I have the main code which is where the function is called(and every other function that the exercise has) and I am not allowed to change ABSOLUTELY NOTHING, everything has to be done inside the function. This is why this is so hard for me, but besides that I tested your code in another file and it works perfectly.

Comment: That's good news!  If you're not allowed to change nothing - then you can and should change EVERYTHING ;)

Comment: @Stephn Lechner - great solution.  Minor quibble - I'd use `fscanf(fp, "%99s", str)`, just in case the file happened to contain any 100++ character words.